# Import CSS dentro de otro CSS y laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

Estoy cargando un template para el área de administrador y resulta que el css matriz style.css en su código tiene import de otros css que también tengo, el problema es que no se me cargan esos css y no entiendo como incluirlos dentro de Laravel Mix, a continuación les muestro como tengo organizado lo assets.

Carpeta Assets

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Style.css tiene lo siguiente (que es donde me da el problema aunque arregle las rutas quitando scss, etc)

```
@import url(../icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/linea-icons/linea.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.min.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/material-design-iconic- 
 font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
 family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700");
@import url(css/spinners.css);
@import url(css/animate.css);
```

Webpack.mix.js

```
mix.styles([
'resources/assets/template/back/css/style.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/colors/blue.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/spinners.css', 
'resources/assets/template/back/css/style.css'
], 'public/css/all.css')
.scripts([
'resources/assets/template/back/js/jquery.slimscroll',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/waves.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/sidebarmenu.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/dashboard2.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/custom.js',
'resources/assets/template/back/js/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js'
], 'public/js/all.js')
 .js(['resources/assets/js/app.js'],'public/js/app.js');
```

Y este es el error que me da al momento de cargar el template del backend

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?, sé que es básico pero es mi primer proyecto en Laravel (ocupo la versión 5.6)

Comment: Hola amigo, porque no colocas el assets en la carpte public, esta debajo del resources y asi no te va a tomar en el public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que estás cometiendo es que intentas importar archivos CSS que están en una carpeta no pública (resources/assets/template/back/css/....), además el navegador intenta encontrar dichos archivos con enrutamiento relativo, y por eso simplemente no los encuentra.

---

Por lo que veo, creo que no es necesario usar todos esos import en style.css si lo que quieres es poner el contenido de todos esos archivos en uno solo (all.css).

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer copiar todos esos archivos (en el orden que necesites) en un solo archivo de CSS, de hecho actualmente lo haces pero parcialmente:

```
mix.styles([
'resources/assets/template/back/css/style.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/colors/blue.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/spinners.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/linea-icons/linea.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/themify-icons/themify-icons.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.min.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/icons/material-design-iconic-font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/spinners.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/animate.css',
'resources/assets/template/back/css/style.css'
], 'public/css/all.css');
```

Sé que las rutas aquí mostradas no coinciden con las tuyas, pero es para mostrarte el ejemplo, en el archivo style.css puedes dejar el import de las fuentes de google y supongo que tu css personalizado.

Comment: ¿Entonces no habría problema en eliminar los import que están dentro de style.css y pasarlos solamente en LaraMix para que este genere un puro archivo?

Comment: Es correcto, no habría problema, y de hecho lo consideraría una mejor práctica en este caso.

Comment: Lo haré de inmediato y te comento

Comment: todo anda bien salvo los iconos de font-awesome y material design que son los archivos font, ttf, woff y svg, ¿como tendría que configurar estos últimos?

Comment: Tendrías que mirar como está incluyendo su contenido en el archivo final, y mirar qué no funciona bien.

Comment: los mismos css hacen llamadas import a esas librerías -> src: url('..//fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');

Comment: Entonces necesitas incluir dichos archivos ubicados correctamente (según su ruta relativa) en la carpeta public.

Comment: Todo en orden, gracias por ser un real apoyo.