# archivo resources/css/app.css no esta, laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

espero se encuentren bien, tengo un problema con mi proyecto laravel 5.8 con laravel mix, no esta la carpeta `css` (y por ende tampoco el archivo `app.css`) en `resources`, solo esta `js`, `lang`, `sass` y `views`, probe con `npm install` y `npm run dev` y nada.

Al realizar el `npm run dev` o `npm run watch`, me muestra esto, como si estuviera la carpeta con el archivo `app.css`:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 9931ms                                                                                                                          17:24:37

       Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css  179 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  1.5 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
```

EDIT: asi tengo el archivo webpack.mix.js :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

a que se debe esto?. Gracias

Comment: fijate de este post tal vez te sirva lo que esta sucediendo seguramente es que tu carpeta de resources no esta. que tu css debe ser importado dentro de un archivo el cual ejecute todas las hojas de estilo si esta escrito en el preprocessor sass o como cualquier preprocesador. si solo estas importando los assetes desde un template te puede servir :


  [1]: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152747/import-css-dentro-de-otro-css-y-laravel-mix?rq=1

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ahi añadi el contenido del archivo

Comment: Bien, efectivamente se está compilando el contenido de `app.scss` en `public/css/app.css` de acuerdo a la instrucción `mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ entonces deberia de quedar algo asi?:  `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/scss')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.css', 'public/css') `

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras hacer... Podrías simplemente usar el archivo app.scss para los estilos y laravel-mix los pasará a css plano para que el navegador lo entienda. Habiendo respondido a la pregunta: *"archivo resources/css/app.css no esta. ¿a qué se debe?"* ¿Cuál es el problema con que te encuentras ahora?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ahhh, ya entendi, pensaba que habia algun error de compilacion o algo asi en mi proyecto, muchas gracias por explicarme! :)

Comment: Vale. Laravel-mix soporta varios procesadores de estilos: Less, Sass, PostCSS o Css plano. Puedes leer más en la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#working-with-stylesheets